# Calling getBoundingClientRect for a span returns wrong position on Chromium, but works on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<p>` element, with an empty span element inside, i.e. `<span id="marker"></span>`. When I ask for `getBoundingClientRect` in Chromium, I get a rectangle with the x,y coordinates of the `<p>` element. Instead, Firefox returns the position of the span inside the text.

Is there something I can do to find out the position of the span in Chromium?

A minimal example to show the issue:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("paragraph-0").getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(document.getElementById("span1").getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(document.getElementById("span2").getBoundingClientRect());
```

```html
<p id="paragraph-0">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<span id="span1"></span>consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt purus at vulputate suscipit. Pellentesque magna eros, convallis eget hendrerit at, porta vitae mi. Aenean eu nunc a enim egestas venenatis eget eu purus.
  Integer dignissim nibh eget enim tincidunt aliquet. Duis in arcu ornare, imperdiet tortor et, pretium lacus. In lectus risus, rutrum scelerisque blandit et, posuere non ligula. Quisque lectus magna, sodales ac quam a, eleifend tristique sapien. Aenean
  id tempor eros. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi non lorem eu dolor semper cursus. Vestibulum porta sem nunc, eget euismod mauris scelerisque non. Integer scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum.
  Ut ultricies purus arcu, feugiat ornare lacus varius in. Suspendisse eget risus sed nisi imperdiet ornare in vel urna. Donec eget nunc non mauris tempor malesuada <span id="span2"></span>sed eget lorem.
</p>
```

If I run the above on Firefox, I get three distinct rectangles, whereas in Chromium, the three of them will be identical.

Comment: After some further testing, I've found out this only happens with empty spans. A possible (dirty!) fix is to put some sort of invisible unicode character (e.g. `&#x2063`) inside the span. However, I'm still interested if someone has a better answer than this.

Comment: struggling to repro, this looks right to me: https://codepen.io/jenko3000/pen/dybBXBa?editors=1111

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details behind the "browser" of codepen.io, but this looks like a chromium-specific issue. I'm using chromium 77 and the described behaviour occurs

Comment: turns out it was only working because I'd added a border - which gave me the idea for a work-around :-)

Comment: Works on Microsoft Edge Version 79.0.279.0 (Official build) dev (64-bit) based on Chromium. The `span`s have a width of 0 since they have no content, but otherwise are fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around a bit, as you note in your OP, it seems that the issue only arises if the span is empty and has no border etc.

However, if a `span` *does* have a border then it reports its position correctly. So one easy way to fix this is to apply a 0.1px transparent border to your spans.

```js
const el1 = document.getElementById("paragraph-0").getBoundingClientRect();
const el2 = document.getElementById("span1").getBoundingClientRect();
const el3 = document.getElementById("span2").getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(el1, el2, el3)
```

```css
#span1, #span2{
  border:0.1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<p id="paragraph-0">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<span id="span1"></span>consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tincidunt purus at vulputate suscipit. Pellentesque magna eros, convallis eget hendrerit at, porta vitae mi. Aenean eu nunc a enim egestas venenatis eget eu purus.
  Integer dignissim nibh eget enim tincidunt aliquet. Duis in arcu ornare, imperdiet tortor et, pretium lacus. In lectus risus, rutrum scelerisque blandit et, posuere non ligula. Quisque lectus magna, sodales ac quam a, eleifend tristique sapien. Aenean
  id tempor eros. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi non lorem eu dolor semper cursus. Vestibulum porta sem nunc, eget euismod mauris scelerisque non. Integer scelerisque sollicitudin rutrum.
  Ut ultricies purus arcu, feugiat ornare lacus varius in. Suspendisse eget risus sed nisi imperdiet ornare in vel urna. Donec eget nunc non mauris tempor malesuada <span id="span2"></span>sed eget lorem.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This does look less hacky than relying on unicode invisible characters